# converting each element from string to int in nested list in python

Tags: python, data-structures, nested-lists

I have data in python with nested lists, a part of which looks like:

```
data = [['214', '205', '0', '14', '710', '1813494849', '0'], ['214', '204', '0', '30', '710', '1813494856', '0'], ['214', '204', '0', '34', '710', '1813494863', '0'], ['213', '204', '0', '35', '710', '1813494870', '0'], ['213', '203', '0', '35', '710', '1813494877', '0']]
```

While converting the data using couple methods:

1.

```
 new_data_list = [[int(x) for x in list] for list in data]
```

2. ```
     list=[]
     for i in range(0,len(data)):
         list.append([])
         for j in range(0,len(data[i])):
             b=int(data[i][j])
             list[i].append(b)
   ```

I am getting the error which says:

```
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

There are no non-numeric data in my list of data. But there might be something with the header, like an empty header treated as non-numeric value as I have created a list of data from csv.

I wanted to know an efficient way which can convert each element of the list to int while keeping the data multi list.

Comment: Side note: *never* shadow built-in `list`, e.g. use `L` or `list_` instead.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either method that you showed, fundamentally. The problem is that your **actual** data contains empty strings (`''`), which **cannot be converted to `int` individually** like this.

Answer (score 7):

Call `int` for each item in each nested list:

```
new_list = [[int(x) for x in lst] for lst in nested]
```

Or using `map`:

```
new_list = [list(map(int, lst)) for lst in nested]
```

Comment: I tried this but it shows this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @TheNoviceProgrammer it looks like there's a non-numeric value in your input. You should have mentioned that in the question. So now, what would you like to do with non-numeric values?

Comment: There are no non-numeric values in my data. I think it might me the header which is not visible in the list, as I have created the list of data using readcsv

Comment: @TheNoviceProgrammer in `data` in the question, there are no non-numeric values, and you should not get any `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

A concise one is:

```py
x = ['123', '12', '5']
r = list(map(int, x))
print(r)
>[123, 12, 5]
```